# The custom type is not recognised when running ps1 script from batch file

Tags: powershell

Custom type that is being used as a return type of a function is not recognized when executing from .bat file.

I have a PS v2.0 script to implement inheritance by class.

The base class contains a  method like getSessionOption that returns a `WinScp.SessionOption` object. This is a utility script to sftp files to remote server. Now the server credential varies according to components, like I have to transfer files either server A, B or C. But script is same for all.

Just to make the credential logic separate from server to server, I have used multiple derived classes that inherits the base class as mentioned. like `ASessionOption`, `BSessionOption` etc is has its own version of `getSessionOption` method.

The problem:

When I am running the script from Poweshell command then it is producing the right result. But when trying to execute the script through a batch file(.bat) then the reference of `WinScp.SessionOption` is not recognized.

Though I have used App-Path to load the right assembly reference and that is why no issue found when executed from Powershell command window.

Comment: You need to include the relevant code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'd also recommend reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as this covers the basics of a good question.

Comment: How are you doing that? PS 2.0 doesn't support classes, and it wasn't introduced until v5. Do you just mean a custom type? Please post your code

Comment: treblecode, thanks for your reply. Yes. there is a typo . I am using Power shell version 5.0. The code snippet on ps1 is given below --->   # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
   Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

   class SessionOptionFactory{

   [WinSCP.SessionOption]getSessionOptions(){

     return New-Object WinSCP.SessionOption


   }

   }

So I am geting no issue when run from undrerneith command window.

But it seems [WinSCP.SessionOption] is unkonwn to the code when running from .bat file the code on bat file 

powershell  -Command ./test.ps1